# Sencha CMD and Compass

Tags: extjs4, sass, compass-sass

We would like to use the Sencha cmd tool. But we work on an intranet that doesn't have access to the internet to download Compass which is required by Sencha cmd. We went to the Compass site and it explains that we need to run the gem tool to download and install Compass. But I didn't see anyway to get Compass installed without having access to the internet and running the gem tool.

Does anyone know how we can install compass and its requirements on our closed network? What do we need to download and install in order to run Sencha cmd if we can't access the internet from our network?

Comment: How did you install Sencha Cmd without access to the internet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a way to bring in files from outside of your intranet, you could in theory make the gem yourself and install it locally.

1. Download the Compass source (https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass)
2. Compile the gem:  `gem build compass.gemspec`
3. Pass the `compass-[version].gem` around to wherever you want Compass installed
4. Install the gem:  `sudo gem install compass`

Gem installation should prioritize local versions over remote versions.  If you can find the Compass gem, you can jump straight to step #3.

Comment: Found out I can download all gems from here too: http://rubygems.org/gems/compass